# Баг с AMD Vi при установке Arch Linux

Tags: linux, archlinux, amd, x86-64

Попытался сегодня поставить `ArchLinux`.
Всё идёт отлично до того момента(За исключением несовместимости подсветки экрана), когда начинается загрузка `AMD Vi`.
Сама ошибка:

> amd-vi completion-wait loop timed out.

О ноутбуке:

- `Dell inspiron 5565`
- `(AMD A10 9600p + r7 440m)`
- Бутменеджер: `rEFInd`
- `BIOS:1.0.6`(Последняя версия)

Режим загрузки: `UEFI GPT(Без Secure Boot'a)`.
В линуксе я почти ноль, так что прошу прощения за нубский вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо просто запустить ядро с данными параметрами:

```
amd_iommu=off iommu=soft
```

Однако, после этого аппаратная виртуализация станет недоступна.

(Что сделает невозможным работу x64-битной ОС в VirtualBox)

Answer (score 0):

Если нужна виртуализация, используйте более старую версию ядра, при загрузки которого этой ошибки нет. Например, в моём случае ядро версии 4.6.7, работает виртуализация и нет ошибки (xubuntu 17.04). Подобное должно работать и на других ОС.